# How WCF service and consumer client exchange keys for certificate?

Tags: encryption, certificate, public-key-encryption

I read a simplification about how public and private keys work on [security.stackexchange.com: How can I explain the concept of public and private keys without technical jargon?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25741/how-can-i-explain-the-concept-of-public-and-private-keys-without-technical-jargo).

Whatever I understood from there: private key sat at owner and owner send a encrypted data to some one along with public key. Public key decrypts that data at client side and also encrypt data of client sent to owner. Once the data is encrypted at client side by public key then the same public key can not reused to encrypt that data. Only the owner of the private key can encrypt and decrypt data as many as time.

Am I right whatever I understood?

My question is: how public key is travel from owner side to client side?

Every time the same public key will be sent from server end to client end or ever time the different public key will be send from server end to client end?

@Ewan said as follows:

1. Client : Sends "Hello"
2. Server : Here is my public key
3. Server : Please send your public key
4. Client : Here is my (encrypted with server public key)public key
5. Client : Here is an (encrypted with server public key)request
6. Server : Here is an (encrypted with client public key)response

This raises the following questions at said steps:

1. When first time client send Hello to server then how hello
   will travel to server in encrypted way?
2. Do not understand why server find his public key?
3. Why server request client to send his public key?

Comment: _"Please explain to me in full detail how key exchange works"_ is too broad for Stack Overflow. Also, as you're nearing your 250th question, you may want to read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) once again. Please also try to use the shift button once and again. A sentence starts with a capital letter, and "I" is always capitalized in English.

Comment: Please educate yourself. Read [Wiki: Key exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_exchange), [Wiki: Diffie–Hellman key exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) and if that's still too much text, see the [picture that explains it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange#/media/File:Diffie-Hellman_Key_Exchange.svg).

Answer (score 1):

No you are wrong:

1. PersonA : creates public and private key pair
2. PersonA : Sends Public Key(A) to PersonB
3. PersonB : Encrypts data with Public Key(A)
4. PersonB : Sends encrypted Data to PersonA
5. PersonA : Decrypts encrypted Data with Private Key(A)

WCF can be setup to do multiple types of encryption and protocols but essentialy what i think you are asking boils down to

Handshake protocol:

1. Client : Sends "Hello" (not encrypted)
2. Server : Here is my public key (**ServerPublicKEY** = "123")
3. Server : Please send your public key
4. Client : Here is my public key (**ClientPublicKEY** = "ABC")
5. Client : Here is an (encrypted with **ServerPublicKEY**)request
6. Server : Decrypt with **server** private key and read
7. Server : Here is an (encrypted with **ClientPublicKEY**)response
8. Client : decrypt with **client** private key

to answer your additional questions

q1: "When first time client send Hello to server then how hello will travel to server in encrypted way?"

a1: It is not encrypted

q2: "Do not understand why server find his public key?"

a2: the server sends a public key so that the client can encrypt messages to send to the server

q3: "Why server request client to send his public key?"

a3: The server needs the clients public key so it can encrypt messages to send to the client

Comment: i like to know when first time PersonA send data to PersonB then encrypted data will not travel from PersonA side to PersonB side. first time PersonB made a request to WCF service and WCF service will send response in encrypted way....i guess i am right. when service send response in encrypted format then how PersonB can read without decrypt it.

Comment: the steps u said creating confusion for me. service is always initiated by consumer. so when consumer send request to wcf service then wcf should return the data in encrypted format along with public key. another every time service will send same public key to consumer or public key will be different every time send by wcf service ?

Comment: so server public key and client public key is different ?

Comment: it is bit confusing : u said server send public key to client to encrypt message and again u said server needs the clients public key so it can encrypt messages. when server is sending public key to client it means the public key server is sending it is saved some where in server side then why server again ask client to send client public key.......this is not clear!

Comment: there are 2 public(client and server) and 2 private(client and server) keys

Comment: please explain the role of two public and two private keys. thanks

Comment: private keys are used for decrypting and are never sent. they can only decrypt thing encrypted by the corresponding public key